# Passing data from a javascript function in my remote website to a c# application on my desktop application

Tags: c#, php, mysql, chromium-embedded, cefsharp

I have a dynamic program. These are the steps that the program follows.

**i)** I have a windows form application and I have divided the window into two parts. One part contains a ChromiumWebBrowser where it loads a remote website (like www.abc.com). The other part does normal operations of fetching data from a wampserver MYSQL DATABASE installed on the local computer and gives output on the same window division.

**ii)** Now I use the Chromium web browser to import data from the remote website and send it to a local php file in the local wampserver and then inside the php file I send the data to appropriate local database tables.

**iii)** When the remote website loads, there is a button "Import data" and then this importation is processed via an AJAX call and now it is in the ajax success: function(){ } that I send the data to my local php file. (I have control over both remote and local wampservers)

**iv)** NOW MY QUESTION IS how do I pass the data from the external javascript ajax to my c# application so that I don't need to have the local php file i.e. The received data will be sent to database directly from c#

**v)** And are there any security threats in the process?

I hope I'm was clear, Any suggestions are welcome

Comment: Try calling a `C#` WebMethod in your ajax Success function.

Comment: @MattMurdock please give a simple demo if you don't mind

Comment: What `CEF` wrapper are you using?

Comment: @amaitland I'm using Cefsharp version on the .net

Comment: You should tag your post accordingly then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest option is to implement a custom `scheme`. So for example you would make your requests to `custom://ajax/uploadToDatabase`. You can then parse the request, update the database and respond accordingly.

http://rawgit.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/master/CefSharp.Example/Resources/Home.html#features-custom-schemes

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/cefsharp/45/CefSharp.Example/CefSharpSchemeHandler.cs#L51

The `CefSharp.WinForms.Example` and `CefSharp.Wpf.Example` projects both provide a working implementation. They're available on `GitHub`

https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp

Comment: A little outdated http://thechriskent.com/2014/04/21/use-local-files-in-cefsharp/